# Duplicated Records on DataGridView - closed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

How can I remove the duplicated records showing in the DataGridView? When I try to search for a record with for example the keyword "dev", the DataGridView will display all the records with "dev" in them, row 1 to 15 have "dev" in them, BUT, after the 15th row, there is another set of records which is exactly the same as the 1st row to 15th row. How can I remove these?

[image]
The whole image is confidential so I cropped it to the minimum size possible.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet.Tasks_Of_Offices' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Tasks_Of_OfficesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Tasks_Of_Offices)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet.Roadmap' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.RoadmapTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Roadmap)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet.Project' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.ProjectTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.Project)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Database1DataSet.OPR' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.OPRTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Database1DataSet.OPR)
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnserch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnserch.Click
        Search_Record()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Search_Record()
        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
        'try catch block is used to catch the error

        Try
            'get connection string declared in the Module1.vb and assign it to conn variable
            conn = New OleDbConnection(Get_Constring)
            conn.Open()
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            sSQL = "SELECT ID, Name, Manager, Office, ContactNr, Researcher, Initiatives FROM [Project]"
            If Me.cbSearch.Text = "Project" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "where Name like '%" & Me.sbox.Text & "%'"
                projectdg.Visible = True
                oprdg.Visible = False
                rmdg.Visible = False
                toodg.Visible = False
            Else
                MsgBox("No Record Found")
            End If
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)

            sSQL = "SELECT ID, Name, Manager, Office, ContactNr, Researcher, Initiatives FROM [Project]"
            If Me.cbSearch.Text = "Project" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "where Manager like '%" & Me.sbox.Text & "%'"
                projectdg.Visible = True
                oprdg.Visible = False
                rmdg.Visible = False
                toodg.Visible = False
            Else
                MsgBox("No Record Found")
            End If
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)

            sSQL = "SELECT ID, Name, Manager, Office, ContactNr, Researcher, Initiatives FROM [Project]"
            If Me.cbSearch.Text = "Project" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "where Office like '%" & Me.sbox.Text & "%'"
                projectdg.Visible = True
                oprdg.Visible = False
                rmdg.Visible = False
                toodg.Visible = False
            Else
                MsgBox("No Record Found")
            End If
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)

            sSQL = "SELECT ContactNr, Researcher FROM [Project]"
            If Me.cbSearch.Text = "Project" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "where ContactNr like '%" & Me.sbox.Text & "%'"
                projectdg.Visible = True
                oprdg.Visible = False
                rmdg.Visible = False
                toodg.Visible = False
            Else
                MsgBox("No Record Found")
            End If
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)

            sSQL = "SELECT ID, Name, Manager, Office, ContactNr, Researcher, Initiatives FROM [Project]"
            If Me.cbSearch.Text = "Project" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "where Researcher like '%" & Me.sbox.Text & "%'"
                projectdg.Visible = True
                oprdg.Visible = False
                rmdg.Visible = False
                toodg.Visible = False
            Else
                MsgBox("No Record Found")
            End If
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)

            sSQL = "SELECT ID, Name, Manager, Office, ContactNr, Researcher, Initiatives FROM [Project]"
            If Me.cbSearch.Text = "Project" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "where Initiatives like '%" & Me.sbox.Text & "%'"
                projectdg.Visible = True
                oprdg.Visible = False
                rmdg.Visible = False
                toodg.Visible = False
            Else
                MsgBox("No Record Found")
            End If
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)

            Me.projectdg.DataSource = dt
            If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
                MsgBox("No Record Found")
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ErrorToString)
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So, waiting for an answer made my hair white. I've already found an answer to my question. so i add a code in this part

```
 sSQL = "SELECT ID, Name, Manager, Office, ContactNr, Researcher, Initiatives FROM [Project]"
            If Me.cbSearch.Text = "Project" Then
                sSQL = sSQL & "where Name like '%" & Me.sbox.Text & "%'"
                projectdg.Visible = True
                oprdg.Visible = False
                rmdg.Visible = False
                toodg.Visible = False
            Else
                MsgBox("No Record Found")
            End If
            cmd.CommandText = sSQL
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            da.Fill(dt)
```

which is RemoveDuplicateRows(dt, "nameofcolumn")
and added another code which is this one,

```
 Public Function RemoveDuplicateRows(ByVal dTable As DataTable, ByVal colName As String) As DataTable
        Dim hTable As New Hashtable()
        Dim duplicateList As New ArrayList()
        For Each dtRow As DataRow In dTable.Rows
            If hTable.Contains(dtRow(colName)) Then
                duplicateList.Add(dtRow)
            Else
                hTable.Add(dtRow(colName), String.Empty)
            End If
        Next
        For Each dtRow As DataRow In duplicateList
            dTable.Rows.Remove(dtRow)
        Next
        Return dTable
    End Function
```